# How can I use the RGBA code which is given in a Figma file?

Tags: flutter, colors, figma

I have given with the Figma file but the color is not matching with the RGBA in flutter code.

[image: figma file screenshot]

Comment: what do you mean with " is not matching"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use this function `Color.fromRGBO(0, 82, 204, 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
Color.fromARGB(int opacity, int red, int green, int blue)
```

with opacity value 1 being not transparent and 0 fully transparent!